# Thread.Sleep vs Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I know that `Thread.Sleep` blocks a thread.

But does `Task.Delay` also block? Or is it just like `Timer` which uses one thread for all callbacks (when not overlapping)?

*([**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0) question doesn't cover the differences)*

Comment: Here's a little [wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx) with a demo highlighting some blocking differences between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread.Sleep(2500) vs. Task.Delay(2500).Wait()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052381/thread-sleep2500-vs-task-delay2500-wait)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The documentation on MSDN is disappointing, but decompiling `Task.Delay` using Reflector gives more information:

```
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (millisecondsDelay < -1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsDelay", Environment.GetResourceString("Task_Delay_InvalidMillisecondsDelay"));
    }
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return FromCancellation(cancellationToken);
    }
    if (millisecondsDelay == 0)
    {
        return CompletedTask;
    }
    DelayPromise state = new DelayPromise(cancellationToken);
    if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
    {
        state.Registration = cancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC(delegate (object state) {
            ((DelayPromise) state).Complete();
        }, state);
    }
    if (millisecondsDelay != -1)
    {
        state.Timer = new Timer(delegate (object state) {
            ((DelayPromise) state).Complete();
        }, state, millisecondsDelay, -1);
        state.Timer.KeepRootedWhileScheduled();
    }
    return state;
}
```

Basically, this method is just a timer wrapped inside of a task. So yes, you can say it's just like timer.

Comment: Does it blocks or not ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't understand your question. It's a task, whether it blocks or not all depends on the way you use it.

Comment: Think of "await Task.Delay(1000)" as the async version of Thread.Sleep(1000), as it doesn't block. I use it in GUI tools when I need to wait but don't want to block the UI or eat up threads.

Answer (score 4):

No, the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) doesn't block the current thread. It *can* be used to block it, but it doesn't do it by itself, and it's rarely used as a synchronous blocker in practice. All it actually does is to return a `Task` that will complete after the specified amount of time:

```
Task task = Task.Delay(1000); // The task will complete after 1,000 milliseconds.
```

Typically this task is then waited asynchronously with the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) keyword, inside an [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) method:

```
await task; // Suspends the async method, but doesn't block the thread.
```

The `await` keyword suspends the current execution flow (async method) until the awaitable completes. No thread is blocked while the execution flow is suspended.

It is also possible to block the current thread until the task completes, by using the synchronous [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) method.

```
task.Wait(); // Blocks the thread.
```

If you would like to see an experimental demonstration that the `await Task.Delay()` doesn't block a thread, here is one. The program below creates a huge number of tasks, where each task awaits a internally a `Task.Delay(1000)`. Then the number of [threads used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.threads) by the current process is printed in the console, and finally all of the tasks are awaited:

```
Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 100_000).Select(async _ =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Tasks: {tasks.Count(t => t.IsCompleted):#,0} / {tasks.Length:#,0}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
Console.WriteLine($"Threads.Count: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count:#,0}");
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine($"Tasks: {tasks.Count(t => t.IsCompleted):#,0} / {tasks.Length:#,0}");
```

Output:

```
Tasks: 0 / 100,000
Threads.Count: 9
Tasks: 100,000 / 100,000
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VziTIK).

The program completes after just 1 second, and reports that during its peak it used a total of 9 threads. If each of the 100,000 tasks blocked a thread, we would expect to see 100,000 threads used at that point. Apparently this didn't happen.

Comment: Just a comment, but the thread count after the WhenAll is 14.

Comment: @JoshMouch I guess that when the 100,000 tasks completed, each one used briefly a thread from the `ThreadPool`. So the `ThreadPool` created a few threads to satisfy the demand, probably 4 threads. This could explain the increase from 9 to 13 total threads. I have no theory about the 14th thread.