# Thread.Sleep(2500) vs. Task.Delay(2500).Wait()

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I want some clarity on this.  I know that `Task.Delay` will internally use a Timer and it is obviously task-based (awaitable), whereas `Thread.Sleep` will cause the thread to be blocked.  However, does calling `.Wait` on the task cause the thread to be blocked?

If not, one would assume that `Task.Delay(2500).Wait()` is better than `Thread.Sleep(2500)`.  This is slightly different that the [SO question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep) as I'm calling `.Wait()`.

Comment: Why would it be better?

Comment: Yes, `.Wait()` on a `Task` is a blocking call. From your perspective, they would essentially be equivalent.

Comment: With such similar functionality offered by your 2 options, I think you really need to clarify what you mean by "better".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `Wait` on an uncompleted task is indeed blocking the thread until the task completes.

Using `Thread.Sleep` is clearer since you're explicitly blocking a thread instead of implicitly blocking on a task.

The only way using `Task.Delay` is preferable is that it allows using a `CancellationToken` so you can cancel the block if you like to.

Comment: ...But only if you have another thread running that can use the `CancellationToken` as the main thread will be blocked.

Comment: @BradleyUffner well, you can create a self cancelling token (using a timer internally)...

Answer (score 7):

`Thread.Sleep(...)` creates an event to wake you up in X millisec, then puts your Thread to sleep... in X millisec, the event wakes you up.

`Task.Delay(...).Wait()` creates an event to start a Task in X millisec, then puts your Thread to sleep until the Task is done (with Wait)... in X millisec, the event starts the Task which ends immediately and then wakes you up.

Basically, they are both very similar. The only difference is if you want to wake up early from another Thread, you won't hit the same method.

Comment: "Task.Delay(...).Wait() creates an event to start a Task in X millisec, then puts your Thread to sleep until the Task is done" There's no task being created here.

Comment: Yes there is one, but it's empty. Delay returns a Task object.

Comment: Yeah badly formulated. No task is ever *started*. There's just a task object which is created by the TaskCompletionSource and whose state is updated after a while.