# Diference between task.wait , Task.delay and thread.sleep

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I would like to know the difference between 
Task.delay Task.Wait and Thread.sleep

When we are using thread.sleep. After wake up from sleep a new stack is getting created. Please let me what is real difference between them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi My question was on wait , delay and sleep. I think this link, they are talking only about delay and sleep.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically `Wait()` and `Sleep()` are both thread blocking operations,in other words they force a thread to sit idle instead of doing work elsewhere. `Delay` on other hand uses a timer internally that releases the thread in use until the delay is complete.

There is much more that can be said about these three functions so here's a small sample set for further reading.

**More Info**

- [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)
- [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
- [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/7339946)
- [Thread.Sleep vs Task.Delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17258816/7339946)
- [Thread.Sleep is a sign of a poorly designed program.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/)

---

```
public class WaitSleepDelay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The thread is released and is alerted when the delay finishes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Delay()
    {
        //This Code Executes
        await Task.Delay(1000); 
        //Now this code runs after 1000ms
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This blocks the currently executing thread for the duration of the delay.
    /// This means that the thread is held hostage doing nothing 
    /// instead of being released to do more work.
    /// </summary>
    public void Sleep()
    {
        //This Code Executes
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Now this code runs after 1000ms
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This blocks the currently executing thread for the duration of the delay
    /// and will deadlock in single threaded sync context e.g. WPF, WinForms etc. 
    /// </summary>
    public void Wait()
    {
        //This Code Executes
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        //This code may never execute during a deadlock
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation. So you mean to say thread.sleep and task.wait create a new stack on resume?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _create a new stack_?