# How Do I Create a Looping Service inside an C# Async/Await application?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have written a class with a method that runs as a long-running Task in the thread pool. The method is a monitoring service to periodically make a REST request to check on the status of another system.  It's just a while() loop with a try()catch() inside so that it can handle its own exceptions and and gracefully continuing if something unexpected happens.

Here's an example:

```
public void LaunchMonitorThread()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check system status
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. Resuming on next loop...");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine, but I want to know if there's another pattern I could use that would allow the Monitor method to run as regular part of a standard Async/Await application, instead of launching it with Task.Run() -- basically I'm trying to avoid fire-and-forget pattern.

So I tried refactoring the code to this:

```
   public async Task LaunchMonitorThread()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check system status

                //Use task.delay instead of thread.sleep:
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. Resuming on next loop...");
            }
        }

    }
```

But when I try to call the method in another async method, I get the fun compiler warning:

"Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed."

Now I *think* this is correct and what I want. But I have doubts because I'm new to async/await. **Is this code going to run the way I expect or is it going to DEADLOCK or do something else fatal?**

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914302/diference-between-task-wait-task-delay-and-thread-sleep

Comment: Isn't that still fire-and-forget regardless? And isn't that what you basically want?

Comment: If you call this Task-returning method without awaiting it, you're still doing fire-and-forget. That's what the compiler warning is about. The main difference is that in the second example the monitoring logic will be scheduled on the main context/thread whereas the first example will keep it running on the  threadpool. It shouldn't block the thread though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are really looking for is the use of a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Use the one in the [System.Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. There is no need to use `Task` or any other variation thereof (for the code sample you have shown).

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
void StartTimer()
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerExecution, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}

void TimerExecution(object state)
{
    try
    {
        //Check system status
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. Resuming on next loop...");
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals

---

You could also use [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) but you might not need it. For a comparison between the 2 Timers see also [System.Timers.Timer vs System.Threading.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1416803/1260204).

Answer (score 2):

If you need fire-and-forget operation, it is fine. I'd suggest to improve it with  `CancellationToken`

```
public async Task LaunchMonitorThread(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            //Check system status

            //Use task.delay instead of thread.sleep:
            await Task.Delay(5000, token);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred. Resuming on next loop...");
        }
    }

}
```

besides that, you can use it like

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
var monitorTask = LaunchMonitorThread(cancellationToken);
```

and save task and/or cancellationToken to interrupt monitor wherever you want

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The method `Task.Run` that you use to fire is perfect to start long-running async functions from a non-async method.

You are right: the forget part is not correct. If for instance your process is going to close, it would be neater if you kindly asked the started thread to finish its task.

The proper way to do this would be to use a `CancellationTokenSource`. If you order the `CancellationTokenSource` to `Cancel`, then all procedures that were started using `Tokens` from this `CancellationTokenSource` will stop neatly within reasonable time.

So let's create a class `LongRunningTask`, that will create a long running `Task` upon construction and `Cancel` this task using the `CancellationTokenSource` upon Dispose().

As both the `CancellationTokenSource` as the `Task` implement `IDisposable` the neat way would be to `Dispose` these two when the `LongRunningTask` object is disposed

```
class LongRunningTask : IDisposable
{
    public LongRunningTask(Action<CancellationToken> action)
    {   // Starts a Task that will perform the action
        this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.longRunningTask = Task.Run( () => action (this.cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private readonly Task longRunningTask;
    private bool isDisposed = false;

    public async Task CancelAsync()
    {   // cancel the task and wait until the task is completed:
        if (this.isDisposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException();

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await this.longRunningTask;
    }

    // for completeness a non-async version:
    public void Cancel()
    {   // cancel the task and wait until the task is completed:
        if (this.isDisposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException();

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.longRunningTask.Wait;
    }
}
```

Add a standard Dispose Pattern

```
public void Dispose()
{
     this.Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && !this.isDisposed)
    {   // cancel the task, and wait until task completed:
        this.Cancel();
        this.IsDisposed = true;                 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var longRunningTask = new LongRunningTask( (token) => MyFunction(token)
...
// when application closes:
await longRunningTask.CancelAsync(); // not necessary but the neat way to do
longRunningTask.Dispose();
```

The Action `{...}` has a `CancellationToken` as input parameter, your function should regularly check it

```
async Task MyFunction(CancellationToken token)
{
     while (!token.IsCancellationrequested)
     {
          // do what you have to do, make sure to regularly (every second?) check the token
          // when calling other tasks: pass the token
          await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), token);
     }
}
```

Instead of checking for Token, you could call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. This will throw an exception that you'll have to catch