# Is async await create a thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Both `Thread.Sleep()` and `Task.Delay()` can suspend the execution of a program (thread) for a given timespan. But are there actually suspending the execution? What is the difference? Hopefully some one can trying to answer all the questions above.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: the problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419572/if-async-await-doesnt-create-any-additional-threads-then-how-does-it-make-appl)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the use of async/await create a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265818/does-the-use-of-async-await-create-a-new-thread)

Comment: See also Stephen Cleary: [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Related: [Thread.Sleep vs Task.Delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258428/thread-sleep-vs-task-delay)

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Sleep` is a blocking call. It puts the current thread into a wait state until the timeout period elapses. So yes, `Thread.Sleep` does suspend the current thread.

`Task.Delay` also uses a timer, but it does not block. Instead, it returns a `Task` that completes when that timer fires. So it does not suspend the current thread.

`Task.Delay` is commonly used with `await`, which will suspend the current *method* (not thread). The thread returns from that method and continues executing.

So, `Thread.Sleep` suspends the current thread (and the method it's executing), but `await Task.Delay` will suspend the current *method* without suspending the current thread.