# Javascript's SetTimeout, SetInterval and ClearInterval equivalent in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

In many cases I need to use these functions in C#. My projects has to be .NET 4.0 and following code is the result that I was able to write after reading questions and answers about these functions. I have been using them for a while and didn't have any problems. However, playing with threads is dangerous so I have a doubt if I'm doing it wrong or not.

My question is, are these functions are safe to use; or is there a better way to do it for .NET 4.0?

```
        private static volatile List<System.Threading.Timer> _timers = new List<System.Threading.Timer>();
        private static object lockobj = new object();
        public static void SetTimeout(Action action, int delayInMilliseconds)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
            var cb = new System.Threading.TimerCallback((state) =>
            {
                lock (lockobj)
                    _timers.Remove(timer);
                timer.Dispose();
                action();
            });
            lock (lockobj)
                _timers.Add(timer = new System.Threading.Timer(cb, null, delayInMilliseconds, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite));
        }
        private static volatile Dictionary<Guid, System.Threading.Timer> _timers2 = new Dictionary<Guid, System.Threading.Timer>();
        private static object lockobj2 = new object();
        public static Guid SetInterval(Action action, int delayInMilliseconds)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
            var cb = new System.Threading.TimerCallback((state) => action());
            lock (lockobj2)
            {
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                _timers2.Add(guid, timer = new System.Threading.Timer(cb, null, delayInMilliseconds, delayInMilliseconds));
                return guid;
            }
        }
        public static bool ClearInterval(Guid guid)
        {
            lock (lockobj2)
            {
                if (!_timers2.ContainsKey(guid))
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    var t = _timers2[guid];
                    _timers2.Remove(guid);
                    t.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: JS hasn't timers, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are DOM methods.

Comment: @Teemu - don't be overly-pedantic, you know what the OP meant.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ The comment was not meant overly-pedantic. Just saying, that timers are not built-in features in JavaScript. That might be useful, when trying to find similar features from other languages.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I implement Javascript's setTimeout and clearTimeout functions in C# using Task Parallel Library (TPL):

SetTimeout:

```
public CancellationTokenSource SetTimeout(Action action, int millis) {

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;
    _ = Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(millis);
        if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            action();
    }, ct);

    return cts;
}
```

ClearTimeout:

```
public void ClearTimeout(CancellationTokenSource cts) {
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

How to use:

```
...
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...

var timeout = SetTimeout(() => {

    Console.WriteLine("Will be run in 2 seconds if timeout is not cleared...");

}, 2000);
```

And if you want to cancel the action before it's run:

```
ClearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Be carefull with this implementation. It could cause memory leaks:
`Important: The CancellationTokenSource class implements the IDisposable interface. You should be sure to call the CancellationTokenSource.Dispose method when you have finished using the cancellation token source to free any unmanaged resources it holds.`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Only drawback I could find so far is, if there are running actions, the application cannot exit. While ending the application this function should be called:

```
    public static void Free()
    {
        lock (lockobj)
        {
            foreach (var t in _timers)
                t.Dispose();
            _timers.Clear();
        }
        lock (lockobj2)
        {
            foreach (var key in _timers2.Keys.ToList())
                ClearInterval(key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries to use

```cs
...
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
```

The function itself

```cs
...
private void setTimeout(Func<int> function, int timeout) // Take in a callback and a timeout
{
    Task.Delay(timeout).ContinueWith((Task task) =>      // Use Task to delay the function by the timeout, then call the function "function"
    {
        function();
    });
}
...
```

An example on how to use it

```cs
...
setTimeout(() => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("After 1 second");
    return 0; // By the way, don't miss this line, because or else you'll get an error of not fitting in Function<int>
}, 1000);
...
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! To really help, could you add more explanation about your answer ?

Comment: I have edited it so that there is an explanation