# The difference in the speed of moving objects through the CPU and GPU shader in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

I have been testing moving a lot of objects in Unity through normal C# code and through HLSL shaders. However, there is no difference in speed. FPS remains the same. Different perlin noise is used to change the position. The C# code uses the standard Mathf.PerlinNoise, while the HLSL uses a custom noise function.

### Scenario 1 - Update via C# code only

Object spawn:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject prefab;

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            GameObject createdParticle;
            createdParticle = Instantiate(prefab);
            createdParticle.transform.position = new Vector3(i * 1f, Random.Range(-1f, 1f), j * 1f);
        }
}
```

Code to move an object via C#. This script is added to each created object:

```
private Vector3 position = new Vector3();

private void Start()
{
    position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.PerlinNoise(Time.time, Time.time), transform.position.z);
}

private void Update()
{
    position.y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(transform.position.x / 20f + Time.time, transform.position.z / 20f + Time.time) * 5f;
    transform.position = position;
}
```

### Scenario 2 - via Compute Kernel (GPGPU)

**Part 1: C# client code**

Object spawn, running the calculation on the shader and assigning the resulting value to the objects:

```
public struct Particle
{
    public Vector3 position;
}

[SerializeField]
private GameObject prefab;
[SerializeField]
private ComputeShader computeShader;

private List<GameObject> particlesList = new List<GameObject>();
private Particle[] particlesDataArray;

private void Start()
{
    CreateParticles();
}

private void Update()
{
    UpdateParticlePosition();
}

private void CreateParticles()
{
    List<Particle> particlesDataList = new List<Particle>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            GameObject createdParticle;
            createdParticle = Instantiate(prefab);
            createdParticle.transform.position = new Vector3(i * 1f, Random.Range(-1f, 1f), j * 1f);
            particlesList.Add(createdParticle);
            Particle particle = new Particle();
            particle.position = createdParticle.transform.position;
            particlesDataList.Add(particle);
        }

    particlesDataArray = particlesDataList.ToArray();
    particlesDataList.Clear();
    computeBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(particlesDataArray.Length, sizeof(float) * 7);
    computeBuffer.SetData(particlesDataArray);
    computeShader.SetBuffer(0, "particles", computeBuffer);
}

private ComputeBuffer computeBuffer;
private void UpdateParticlePosition()
{
    computeShader.SetFloat("time", Time.time);
    computeShader.Dispatch(computeShader.FindKernel("CSMain"), particlesDataArray.Length / 10, 1, 1);
    computeBuffer.GetData(particlesDataArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < particlesDataArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pos = particlesList[i].transform.position;
        pos.y = particlesDataArray[i].position.y;
        particlesList[i].transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

**Part 2: Compute kernel (GPGPU)**

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

struct Particle {
    float3 position;
    float4 color;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> particles;
float time;

float mod(float x, float y)
{
    return x - y * floor(x / y);
}

float  permute(float x) { return floor(mod(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x, 289.0)); }
float3 permute(float3 x) { return mod(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x, 289.0); }
float4 permute(float4 x) { return mod(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x, 289.0); }
float taylorInvSqrt(float r) { return 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * r; }
float4 taylorInvSqrt(float4 r) { return float4(taylorInvSqrt(r.x), taylorInvSqrt(r.y), taylorInvSqrt(r.z), taylorInvSqrt(r.w)); }

float3 rand3(float3 c) {
    float j = 4096.0 * sin(dot(c, float3(17.0, 59.4, 15.0)));
    float3 r;
    r.z = frac(512.0 * j);
    j *= .125;
    r.x = frac(512.0 * j);
    j *= .125;
    r.y = frac(512.0 * j);
    return r - 0.5;
}

float _snoise(float3 p) {
    const float F3 = 0.3333333;
    const float G3 = 0.1666667;
    float3 s = floor(p + dot(p, float3(F3, F3, F3)));
    float3 x = p - s + dot(s, float3(G3, G3, G3));

    float3 e = step(float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), x - x.yzx);
    float3 i1 = e * (1.0 - e.zxy);
    float3 i2 = 1.0 - e.zxy * (1.0 - e);

    float3 x1 = x - i1 + G3;
    float3 x2 = x - i2 + 2.0 * G3;
    float3 x3 = x - 1.0 + 3.0 * G3;

    float4 w, d;

    w.x = dot(x, x);
    w.y = dot(x1, x1);
    w.z = dot(x2, x2);
    w.w = dot(x3, x3);

    w = max(0.6 - w, 0.0);

    d.x = dot(rand3(s), x);
    d.y = dot(rand3(s + i1), x1);
    d.z = dot(rand3(s + i2), x2);
    d.w = dot(rand3(s + 1.0), x3);

    w *= w;
    w *= w;
    d *= w;

    return dot(d, float4(52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0));
}

[numthreads(10, 1, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Particle particle = particles[id.x];
    float modifyTime = time / 5.0;
    float positionY = _snoise(float3(particle.position.x / 20.0 + modifyTime, 0.0, particle.position.z / 20.0 + modifyTime)) * 5.0;

    particle.position = float3(particle.position.x, positionY, particle.position.z);
    particles[id.x] = particle;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, why is there no increase in calculation speed? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**TL;DR:** your GPGPU (compute shader) scenario is **unoptimized** thus skewing your results.  Consider binding a material to the `computeBuffer` and rendering via `Graphics.DrawProcedural`.  That way everything stays on the GPU.

---

OP:

> What am I doing wrong, why is there no increase in calculation speed?

Essentially, there are two parts to your problem.

### (1) Reading from the GPU is slow

With most things GPU-related, you generally want to avoid reading from the GPU since it will block the CPU.  This is true also for GPGPU scenarios.

If I were to hazard a guess it would be the GPGPU (compute shader) call `computeBuffer.GetData()` shown below:

```
private void Update()
{
    UpdateParticlePosition();
}

private void UpdateParticlePosition()
{
.
.
.
    computeBuffer.GetData(particlesDataArray); // <----- OUCH!
```

Unity (my emphasis):

> `ComputeBuffer.GetData` 
> Read data values from the buffer into an array...
> Note that this function reads the data back **from the GPU, which can be slow**...If any GPU work has been submitted that writes to this buffer, **Unity waits for the tasks to complete** before it retrieves the requested data.  [Tell me more...](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeBuffer.GetData.html)

### (2) Explicit GPU reading is not required in your scenario

I can see you are creating **2,500** "particles" where each particle is attached to a `GameObject`.  If the intent is to just draw a simple quad then it's more efficient to create an array `struct`s containing a `Vector3` position and then performing a batch render call to draw all the particles in one go.

---

Proof: see video below of nBody simulation. 60+ FPS on 2014 era NVidia card

---

e.g. for my [GPGPU n-Body Galaxy Simulation](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/) I do just that.  Pay attention to the `StarMaterial.SetBuffer("stars", _starsBuffer)` during actual rendering.  That tells the GPU to use the buffer that **already** exists on the GPU, the very same buffer that the computer shader used to move the star positions.  **There is no CPU reading the GPU here.**

```
public class Galaxy1Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D HueTexture;

    public int NumStars = 10000; // That's right! 10,000 stars!

    public ComputeShader StarCompute;
    public Material StarMaterial;
    private ComputeBuffer _quadPoints;
    private Star[] _stars;
    private ComputeBuffer _starsBuffer;
.
.
.
    private void Start()
    {
        _updateParticlesKernel = StarCompute.FindKernel("UpdateStars");
        _starsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(NumStars, Constants.StarsStride);

        _stars = new Star[NumStars];
        // Create initial positions for stars here (not shown)
        _starsBuffer.SetData(_stars);

        _quadPoints = new ComputeBuffer(6, QuadStride);
        _quadPoints.SetData(...); // star quad      
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // bind resources to compute shader
        StarCompute.SetBuffer(_updateParticlesKernel, "stars", _starsBuffer);
        StarCompute.SetFloat("deltaTime", Time.deltaTime*_manager.MasterSpeed);
        StarCompute.SetTexture(_updateParticlesKernel, "hueTexture", HueTexture);

        // dispatch, launch threads on GPU
        var numberOfGroups = Mathf.CeilToInt((float) NumStars/GroupSize);
        StarCompute.Dispatch(_updateParticlesKernel, numberOfGroups, 1, 1);

        // "Look Ma, no reading from the GPU!"
    }

    private void OnRenderObject()
    {
        // bind resources to material
        StarMaterial.SetBuffer("stars", _starsBuffer);
        StarMaterial.SetBuffer("quadPoints", _quadPoints);

        // set the pass
        StarMaterial.SetPass(0);

        // draw
        Graphics.DrawProcedural(MeshTopology.Triangles, 6, NumStars);
    }
}
```

n-Body galaxy simulation of **10,000** stars:
[image]

I think everyone can agree that Microsoft's GPGPU documentation is pretty sparse so your best bet is to check out examples scattered around the interwebs.  One that comes to mind is the excellent *"GPU Ray Tracing in Unity"* series over at Three Eyed Games.  See the link below.

### See also:

- MickyD, *["n-Body Galaxy Simulation using Compute Shaders on GPGPU via Unity 3D"](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/)*, 2014
- Kuri, D, *["GPU Ray Tracing in Unity – Part 1"](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/)*, 2018

Comment: @GoofyGoof not a problem good sir.  Happy GPGPUing :)

Answer (score 1):

ComputeBuffer.GetData is very long. The CPU copies data from the GPU. This stops the main thread.
Then you loop around all transforms to change their positions, this is certainly faster than thousands of MonoBehaviour, but also very long.
There are two ways to optimize your code.

**CPU**

[C# Job System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemOverview.html) + [Burst](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.burst@1.8/manual/docs/QuickStart.html)
Detailed tutorial: https://github.com/stella3d/job-system-cookbook

**GPU**

Use the structured buffer calculated in the compute shader without copying it back to the CPU. Here is a detailed tutorial on how to do it:
https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/basics/compute-shaders/

Comment: C# Job System + Burst will be able to provide the best performance in this task. And it will work on any cell phone without compute shaders. And even if compute shaders are supported, the job system will help to perform all calculations outside of the main thread and not burden the GPU with unnecessary calculations.

Comment: _"will be able to provide the best performance in this task"_ - for questions concerning _performance_ answers should include metrics/facts/citations.  Any thread pool system including Unity's Job System has a hard limit with the CPU and OS.  On Windows each thread uses _["**1 MB** for both native and CLR threads"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2744464/585968)_.  For I/O-bound tasks using threads scales terribly.